# Results order are different in two elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an elasticsearch7 index, with some documents and a second index with the same documents (change only _id)

If I run a query in first index results order are different than run query on second index, but documents are the same! Why?

```
{"query": {"bool": 
{"must": [{"bool": {"must": [{"match": {"distretto": "MI"}}], 
"should": []}}], "should": []}}, 
"_source": ["annosentenza", "cf_giudice", 
"codiceoggetto", "controparte", "id", "nomegiudice", "parte", "text"]}
```

The response, I search with only distretto:MI

civile index returns

eDmNh38BgYGzAMbAifcN -> MI 111002 CIGOLINI CHIARA

2jmNh38BgYGzAMbAlfcv -> MI 230999 INPS

instead paganotti_civile returns

98WLpIQBAcCrPawmBF_o -> MI 140112 SODALITAS SOC. COOP. SOCIALE ONLUS

-MWLpIQBAcCrPawmBV8M -> MI 140022 AM CASALI S.R.L.

I would want for paganotti_civile return the same first page as civile

MI 111002 CIGOLINI CHIARA

MI 230999 INPS

First index(civile)

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.7262077,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "civile",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "eDmNh38BgYGzAMbAifcN",
        "_score" : 2.7262077,
        "_source" : {
          "codiceoggetto" : "111002",
          "controparte" : "CIGOLINI CHIARA",
          "nomegiudice" : "BONIOLO FLAVIANA",
          "annosentenza" : "",
          "cf_giudice" : "BNLFVN76A56F205I",
          "parte" : "ARCAINI GIUSEPPE",
          "id" : "GLMI 87088946 123646"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "civile",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2jmNh38BgYGzAMbAlfcv",
        "_score" : 2.7262077,
        "_ignored" : [
          "text.keyword"
        ],
        "_source" : {
          "codiceoggetto" : "230999",
          "controparte" : "INPS",
          "nomegiudice" : "FEDELE EMANUELA",
          "annosentenza" : "",
          "cf_giudice" : "FDLMNL64D52B300E",
          "parte" : "CIFALDI NICOLA",
          "id" : "GLMI 99957367 27427"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "civile",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ATmNh38BgYGzAMbAmfhY",
        "_score" : 2.7262077,
        "_ignored" : [
          "text.keyword"
        ],
        "_source" : {
          "codiceoggetto" : "220050",
          "controparte" : "ROMEO GESTIONI SPA",
          "nomegiudice" : "FEDELE EMANUELA",
          "annosentenza" : "",
          "cf_giudice" : "FDLMNL64D52B300E",
          "parte" : "RISI LORENA",
          "id" : "GLMI 98349767 27599"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "civile",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "LTmNh38BgYGzAMbAnvgM",
        "_score" : 2.7262077,
        "_ignored" : [
          "text.keyword"
        ],
        "_source" : {
          "codiceoggetto" : "144032",
          "controparte" : "BALDINI ILEANA",
          "nomegiudice" : "ROCA GRAZIA CONCETTA",
          "annosentenza" : "",
          "cf_giudice" : "RCOGZC84P50D643J",
          "parte" : "P.C.E. PRODUZIONE CABLAGGI ELETTRICI S.R.L.",
          "id" : "GLMI 75594601 109890"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "civile",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "hzmNh38BgYGzAMbAqPjU",
        "_score" : 2.7262077,
        "_ignored" : [
          "text.keyword"
        ],
        "_source" : {
          "codiceoggetto" : "220040",
          "controparte" : "COMUNE OGGIONA CON SANTO STEFANO",
          "nomegiudice" : "FEDELE EMANUELA",
          "annosentenza" : "",
          "cf_giudice" : "FDLMNL64D52B300E",
          "parte" : "MAGISTRI MARCO EMILIO",
          "id" : "GLMI 100942914 26946"
        }
      },
```

Second index(paganotti_civile)

```
{
  "took" : 138,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.4119706,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "paganotti_civile",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "98WLpIQBAcCrPawmBF_o",
        "_score" : 0.4119706,
        "_ignored" : [
          "text.keyword"
        ],
        "_source" : {
          "codiceoggetto" : "140112",
          "controparte" : "SODALITAS SOC. COOP. SOCIALE ONLUS",
          "nomegiudice" : "PERTILE ROBERTO",
          "annosentenza" : "",
          "cf_giudice" : "PRTRRT58A14L872W",
          "parte" : "RANZANI GIUSEPPINA",
          "id" : "GLMI 100944044 1964905"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "paganotti_civile",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "-MWLpIQBAcCrPawmBV8M",
        "_score" : 0.4119706,
        "_ignored" : [
          "text.keyword"
        ],
        "_source" : {
          "codiceoggetto" : "140022",
          "controparte" : "AM CASALI S.R.L.",
          "nomegiudice" : "CAPPELLO ADA",
          "annosentenza" : "",
          "cf_giudice" : "CPPDAA87T59C351D",
          "parte" : "BOSSI GIANCARLO",
          "id" : "GLMI 75970798 113201"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "paganotti_civile",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "-cWLpIQBAcCrPawmBV8g",
        "_score" : 0.4119706,
        "_ignored" : [
          "text.keyword"
        ],
        "_source" : {
          "codiceoggetto" : "140051",
          "controparte" : "BUCCI GIORGIO",
          "nomegiudice" : "FERRARI FRANCESCO MATTEO",
          "annosentenza" : "2021",
          "cf_giudice" : "FRRFNC67M20F205B",
          "parte" : "POZZA OTTAVIANO ALVISE",
          "id" : "GLMI 135138291 2299283"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "paganotti_civile",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "-sWLpIQBAcCrPawmBV81",
        "_score" : 0.4119706,
        "_ignored" : [
          "text.keyword"
        ],
        "_source" : {
          "codiceoggetto" : "140041",
          "controparte" : "DI LAURO GENNARO  (AVV.)",
          "nomegiudice" : "RAINERI CARLA ROMANA",
          "annosentenza" : "2020",
          "cf_giudice" : "RNRCLR55E52G535U",
          "parte" : "MONTE DEI PASCHI DI SIENA SPA",
          "id" : "GLMI 101233632 100541"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "paganotti_civile",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "-8WLpIQBAcCrPawmBV9D",
        "_score" : 0.4119706,
        "_ignored" : [
          "text.keyword"
        ],
        "_source" : {
          "codiceoggetto" : "140022",
          "controparte" : "CO.GE.T. SOCIETA  COOPERATIVA IN LIQUIDAZIONE",
          "nomegiudice" : "MANTOVANI ANNA",
          "annosentenza" : "2021",
          "cf_giudice" : "MNTNNA58A68F205S",
          "parte" : "AMIACQUE SRL",
          "id" : "GLMI 131465321 114225"
        }
      },
```

Comment: can you provide the response JSOn from both index?

Comment: Ok, I have exported all documents of distretto MI from index civile and I insert with new _id with the same order in paganotti_civile. If I query distretto MI from civile the order of documents isn't the same of paganotti_civile. I don't put any sort command in query.

Comment: Please provide response json from both index as well as index mapping of the both index ?

Comment: when you get diffrent order of the result then _score having same value or diffrent ? @zabitstack

Comment: the score "max_score" : 0.4119706 of second index, first index is "max_score" : 2.7262077

Comment: Ok I edit my post to add info about json response.

Comment: Realy there are others documents like distretto:VE. But for distretto:MI I checked, there is 
`{
  "count" : 87103,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}`

Comment: Could you also add the index mapping of both indices?